# how to find a class spacefic time in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML with the same class used multiple times like given example below.

```
<div class="exam" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="exam" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="exam" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="exam" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="exam" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="exam" style="display:none"></div>



function removeTopThreeStyles() {
 $("[style=\"display:none\"].exam").slice(0,2).removeAttr('style');
 $("[style=\"display:none\"].exam").slice(0,2).removeClass('exam');
}

 $(".addnewbox").click(function() {
            removeTopThreeStyles(); 
});
```

what I want is to remove style attribute from the first two div upon a click and then again click and remove from the next two div.

Thanks

Comment: Read [:nth-of-type](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/). _The :nth-of-type selector allows you select one or more elements based on their source order, according to a formula._

Comment: Please also share the code attempts that you have tried so far.

Comment: @palaѕн, please check now, is it readable now ?

Comment: @RoyBogado, my you give me little code hint , I have updated question code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

plain JavaScript (no jQuery):

```
function removeTopTwoStyles() {
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll("[style=\"display:none\"].hideyet")
    if(elements.length > 1) {
        elements[0].removeAttribute("style");
        elements[1].removeAttribute("style");
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
function removeTopTwoStyles() {
    $("[style=\"display:none\"].hideyet").slice(0,2).removeAttr('style');
}
```

after that you can trigger it by simply calling `removeTopTwoStyles()` method

*** Answer edited to comply with HTML structure from screenshot ***

Comment: Thanks but no work is working , here is screenshot of how these are in code , https://prnt.sc/ruj71q  you can replace exam class to hideyet

Comment: in that case we need to change the query selector: 
`$("[style=\"display:none\"].hideyet").slice(0, 2).removeAttr('style');`

Comment: I did as you advised it didnt worked ,  if(elements.length > 1) {
        elements[0].removeAttribute("style");
        elements[1].removeAttribute("style");
    }
this logic being failed with javascript, elements length is not coming true

Comment: it seems you are using the plain JavaScript (1st) approach. I will edit my answer according to posted screenshot of your HTML structure so it is a bit more clear to understand

Comment: @GoranLegeda, I used both, elements length coming false, displaying this Error "Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of undefined"

Comment: there  is no exam class in real code, it is replaced with hideyet

Comment: your code is perfect but it snot working on my website, maybe some conflication or jquery issue will be there

Comment: Can you please advise me why elements are coming 0 , i consoled elements AND i am getting this https://prnt.sc/rum4vj

Comment: I did it Thanks, I have removed style attribute and added css code to  the class(display:none)
(function removeTopTwoStyles() {
    $(".exam").slice(0,1)
      .removeClass('exam');
  })

Answer (score 2):

You can try this for removing the first element style which is `div` for example. Add a function to a button and should able to do what you want

```
$("div:nth-of-type(1)").removeAttr("style")
```

Link: https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Comment: thanks , there are many div and class around 2000 lines of code, I just gave part of it , I need it with class

Comment: Do you have a class to wrap all those div?. If yes, you can just choose this:  ```$("<className> div:nth-of-type(1)")```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ruj71q here is a screenshot of divs, exam class is replaced with hideyet

Comment: the ```nth-of-type``` selector should work fine when combining with the class ```ui-sortable```